# C# Math.POW and Manually calculating are coming out with completely different answers... Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: c#

Forgive me if this is already on here somewhere but I couldn't find it.

SO, I am doing a simple calculation.

```
double radius = 2.50;
//double pi = Math.PI;

//double areaOfCircle;

double radSquared = radius * radius;

double radiusSquared = Math.Pow(radius, radius); //This, to me, give the wrong answer..?

//areaOfCircle = Math.PI * radSquared; //This one give the correct calculation
```

Why, if I just do radius * radius do I get an accurate calculation, but when I use the Math.Pow method, I get a completely different answer...?

Surely it is doing the exact same calculation? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=net-5.0).

You are raising radius to the power of radius, not radius to the power of 2.